# Error when using window button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button, tk-toolkit

Here is my code for debugging:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
b1 = window.button(window,text="Dark",command=window.configure(bg='black'))
window.mainloop()
```

I want to add a button to set the bg color to black. Pretty simple. But it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/----/Downloads/windows.py", line 3, in <module>
    b1 = window.button(window,text="Dark",command=window.configure(bg='black'))
  File "C:\Users\----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2383, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'button'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is the answer:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
b1 = Button(window,text="Dark",command=window.configure(bg='black'))
b1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Your mistake was that your input was `b1 = window.button()` instead of `b1 = Button()`

Moreover, you forgot to add in a `b1.pack()` after the `b1 = Button()`

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this code it will run as expected

```py
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(window,text="Dark", command=lambda: window.configure(bg='black'))
b1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

You made several mistakes in it.

1. You use `b1 = window.button`
2. You can't pass function in command like that, you cannot call it directly in command if you need to pass arguments with it you need to pass a **lambda** function like above.
3. You forgot to **pack** the button in the window that is needed to display it.

Comment: While not technically incorrect, it may be better to explicitly import modules and functions needed from tkinter.  `*` imports are not always considered best practice.